# WPF DataGridRow changes a property of a child control upon a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a Grid like this:

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20px" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200px" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode = TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        </CheckBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" >
            <Label Content="{Binding property1}" ></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding property2}" ></Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Click it" x:Name="myCoolbutton" Command="{Binding Parameter}"/>
    </Grid>
```

My plan is to change the Visibility property of the button, if there is a MouseOver event on the grid's row. Actually I tried this with style triggers, but I couldn't reach my goal and it would be delightful, if anyone could give me a hint.

Thank You

**EDIT:** 
Here are some examples of my previous work - It's as a comment, because it doesn't work properly

```
 <Grid.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
     <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <!-- <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="{Binding Rowhover}"></EventSetter>-->
      <!-- <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"></Setter>-->
      </Trigger>
      <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control,AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" >
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
      </DataTrigger>-->
      <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control,AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="copyToClipboardButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
      </DataTrigger>-->
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you tried to do with the style triggers.

Comment: It is easy enough with a Column. But with grid, you have to use some tricks. With code, it is easy with both row and column mouseoverevent.

Comment: @Käsebrot I've added some examples

Comment: @AnjumSKhan any suggestion?

Comment: @Dr.Joe You are trying to hide button, whenever mouse is over the entire Grid (anywhere). But your question is saying something else.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Yep, It should be just the button in that specific row. So the event should be handled by one row not by the entire grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style to the Button and when ever the Mouse is over the grid the EnterActions property will be executed , otherwise the ExitActions will be executed; effectively changing a child control property by binding its Data to an event to one of its ancestors .

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},Path=(IsMouseOver)}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="SomeChildControlProperty" Value="SomeValue" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},Path=(IsMouseOver)}" Value="False">
           <Setter Property="SomeChildControlProperty" Value="SomeValue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I think You can also do this by just using the setter directly inside the DataTrigger, without the EnterActions and ExitActions

Comment: @user2252775 : Yes indeed you can do that directly, in this case i thought it will make sense to show the button when the trigger fires and hide the button when the trigger exists.

Comment: @Ahmad You are doing it for entire Grid, question is about only a specific Row.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan : thanks, i did not realize that from the title, updated the answer now.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan No it is working - The code above is not "complete" but the result will be correct

Comment: @Ahmad Question is about Grid and its Row. With available features of WPF, it is simple not possibly to detect if mouse if over a Row present in the Grid control. Because RowDefinition is not present in the VisualTree. Check this with Snoop tool. So, you have to detect mouse-over in all columns of that Grid.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan : Agreed regarding Row presenter not being part of the visual tree.  In this case then having the ancestor as the Grid will do to trick because we are assigning the style to the child of the Grid; in this particular case a Button control. So if the mouse is over any part of the Grid, then the child control DataTrigger will fire (i don't see how this is different than detecting mouse-over in all columns since that is actually all of the grid contents)

Comment: @Ahmad Read question carefully and comments in the question.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan : I understood the question correctly. Lets assume that the grid the author presented is contained in some ContentControl. For example a ListBoxItem, now lets create two items in that list box. The effect (desired by the author and in the comment section) would be that the above DataTriggers will fire only for specific ContentControl  (i.e., for specific rows).